# fetch next and scan records within the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

**I have the following table**

[image]

data is accessible here

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=18e9473c82deb4e7e955a0b0cb6f5014

**I want to find the employee if he has a city = 'London' and next row after that <> 'London'.
After that I should scan the rest rows and catch first row = 'London', if not i should ignore the entire row.
the result should be like below**

[image]

**My code and result:**

[image]

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cc7863dbe59f80d1058f34a8f7ad0562

**Code works if**

```
first city = London
Second city != London
third city = London
```

**But if London instead of coming as a third city let say fourth or fifth it will not works.
Code should be:**

```
first city = London 
Second city <> London
third city = London if not check next
fourth city = London if not check next
...
to last row for the employee if not find London, skip the entire row.
```

**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `LEAD()` with some `CASE` logic and `IGNORE NULL`s does what you want:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             LEAD(CITY) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY DATETIME) as city_2,
             LEAD(datetime) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY DATETIME) as datetime_2,
             LEAD(CASE WHEN CITY = 'London' THEN CITY END IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY DATETIME) as city_3,
             LEAD(CASE WHEN CITY = 'London' THEN DATETIME END IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY DATETIME) as datetime_3
      FROM MY_TABLE t
     ) t
WHERE CITY = 'London' AND CITY_2 <> 'London' AND CITY_3 = 'London';
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=41647e2b278c075b2438b3498126f4d3) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Amazing its work, I can't understand how IGNORE NULLS works here. do you have explanation thank you.

Comment: @Nawaf . . . The `CASE` expression returns `NULL` when the city is anything other than `'London'`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `aggregate function` as following:

```
SELECT T.EMP_ID, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN MINRN = RANK_CITY THEN CITY END) AS CITY_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN MINRN = RANK_CITY THEN DATETIME END) AS DATE_TIME_1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN MINRN + 1 = RANK_CITY THEN CITY END) AS CITY_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN MINRN + 1 = RANK_CITY THEN DATETIME END) AS DATE_TIME_2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CNTCITY = 2 and CITY= 'London' THEN CITY END) AS CITY_3,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CNTCITY = 2 and CITY ='London' THEN DATETIME END) AS DATE_TIME_3
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             Min(CASE WHEN CITY = 'London' THEN RANK_CITY END) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID) as MINRN,
             SUM(CASE WHEN CITY = 'London' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY DATETIME) AS CNTCITY,
             Max(CASE WHEN CITY = 'London' THEN RANK_CITY END) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID) as MAXRN
      FROM MY_TABLE t
     ) t
WHERE MAXRN - MINRN > 1
GROUP BY EMP_ID
```

[Db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0dccc0ddfb8c72e577af94fad76972c7)

Cheers!!

Comment: Using max and min I think will will not work if the employee had more than one record like emp# 6631583, check the supposed result in my question. thank you.

Comment: Yes, it works except if employee had more than one case like emp 6631583